# How can I find the gtts request per minute/time limit?

Tags: python

I am converting large text into audio files using python and gTTS module. The text is in a python list with each item in the list being a page of text. The issue happens when I feed gTTS the entire text at once (single string). I receive a "429 error (Too many requests) cause unknown" after it converts about an hour of audio. If I can figure out how many requests I can make with gTTS per minute or second then I can just add in delay before each request and send one page at a time. The gTTS documentation does not have any rate limit info and I can not find if anyone has figured this out and posted it. After getting the 429 too many requests I cannot make anymore for at least an hour, so guessing and checking the time delay will take a long time, maybe even days.

Comment: You will probably get that error the first time the limit is exceeded. Why not count how long it takes to reach that limit and how many requests were made. Then you just divide and round down

Comment: The way gTTS works doesn't allow me to know how many requests it is making. I know it takes the text and its tokenizer breaks it into 100 character or less chunks, then makes a request for each chunk. However I can only call gtts_instance.save(filename) once and all that happens behind the scenes. When it crashes I will only know how long it took and not how many characters/chunks/requests it made.